# Difficulties with 3D scatterplot, :

Tags: 3d, scatter-plot

Im trying to create a scatterplot including 3 diffrent datasets where only the z-values are different. That means my x-y coordinates are the same but the z-coordinates are different.

```
3D Plot 
library(scatterplot3d)
s3d6=scatterplot3d  (Mainjib,               # x axis 
                     Knucklejib,            # y axis
                     Sigma_section6,        # z axis
                     color="blue", pch=19,  # filled blue circles
                     type="h",              # lines to the horizontal plane

                   xlab="Hovedbom V.[Grader]",
                   ylab="Knekkbom V.[Grader]",
                   zlab="Spenning [N/mm2]")
 s3d.coords <- s3d$xyz.convert(Mainjib, Knucklejib, Sigma_section6)    
 text(s3d.coords$x, s3d.coords$y,                                      
   labels=row.names(Log.Mat_Sec6),                                  
   cex=.5, pos=4)                                                  

par(new=TRUE)

library(scatterplot3d)
s3d9=scatterplot3d     (Mainjib,               # x axis 
                       Knucklejib,            # y axis
                       Sigma_Section9,        # z axis
                       color="red", pch=19,  # filled red circles
                       type="h",              # lines to the horizontal plane

                    xlab="Hovedbom V.[Grader]",
                    ylab="Knekkbom V.[Grader]",
                    zlab="Spenning [N/mm2]")
 s3d.coords <- s3d$xyz.convert(Mainjib, Knucklejib, Sigma_Section9)    
 text(s3d.coords$x, s3d.coords$y,                                              
 labels=row.names(Log.Mat_Sec9),                                  
 cex=.5, pos=4)
```

This works to some extend but the x-axis and z-axis get bugged, which is shown in the picture. I would also like to add another set of data into the plot but im am not sure how to do it, if someone could help i would be very glad. 
Best reards
  ![Bugged axis][1]

Comment: There's no picture. You won't have enough points to include the picture yet, but if you paste the URL into your question someone with enough points might edit it in for you. However you should also explain how they are "bugged", and how you've tried to add the extra data set.

Comment: ok, thanks for reply. Ive tryed as showen in the code above, by useing the function par(new=TRUE). This works but labels at the axis is printed twice and also the x-y-z space are printed twice, beacuse the 3D space are not 100% equal. I hope ive managed to explain myself.